# Post file and data in same request to node server

Tags: node.js, express, forms, http-post

I have a form in HTML with two inputs - 1 text and 1 file.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/users">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Now I am posting it to a node server-

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res, next){
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename){
        var fstream=fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/'+filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function(){
            var user = User({
                username: req.body.username,
            });
            user.save(function(err){
                if(err)
                    res.json({error: err});
                else
                    res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But I am only able to get either username or file (when I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in HTML form.) at a time.

Is there any way to save both in a single request. If yes then how ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only listening for file fields. If you want to be notified about non-file fields, then you need to also add a `'field'` event listener:

```
req.busboy.on('field', function(key, val, keyTrunc, valTrunc) {
  console.log(key, val);
});
```